# Address is different when using pointer with __block in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, pointers, objective-c-blocks

I have a piece of code which I can not understand the output.

Define a block:

```
typedef void (^TestBlock) ();

void testBlock(int *pt, TestBlock b) {
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(1.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
        *pt = 3;
        NSLog(@"point to address: %p", pt);
        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(1.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            b();
        });
    });
}
```

Use this block in other place:

```
__block int i = 0;
testBlock(&i, ^{

    NSLog(@"block value   %d", i);
    NSLog(@"block address %p", &i);
    i = 2;
});
i = 1;
NSLog(@"real value %d", i);
NSLog(@"real address %p", &i);

dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(3.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    NSLog(@"final value %d", i);
    NSLog(@"final address %p", &i);
});
```

The output is:

```
real value 1
real address 0x7fa353e830d8
point to address: 0x7fff58f37c38
block value   1
block address 0x7fa353e830d8
final value 2
final address 0x7fa353e830d8
```

I don't understand why block value is not "3", and the pointer "pt" point to different address.

Comment: Inside `testBlock` log `pt` and update the output in your question.

Comment: @rmaddy, `pt` is a pointer, it's value is the address of `i`. My question is why `i`'s address is different in and out of blocks.

Comment: I understand all of that. That's why I wanted you to update your question with the details about the pointer inside the block (which you have done).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>First, we need to get out of the way a confounding issue with the order that the argument expressions passed to `testBlock()` are evaluated. In C, the order that arguments are evaluated is undefined. Different orders may produce different results if one of the expressions has side effects. To remove this issue, we need to evaluate each expression separately (in a defined order), store each into a variable, and then pass those variables instead.</s>

You will find that (at least on the current Xcode versions, under ARC) if you evaluate the second argument before the first:

```
TestBlock bar = ^{

    NSLog(@"block value   %d", i);
    NSLog(@"block address %p", &i);
    i = 2;
};
int *foo = &i;
testBlock(foo, bar);
```

it prints `block value   3`. Whereas if you evaluate the first argument before the second:

```
int *foo = &i;
TestBlock bar = ^{

    NSLog(@"block value   %d", i);
    NSLog(@"block address %p", &i);
    i = 2;
};
testBlock(foo, bar);
```

it prints `block value   1`, which is what you see. (As you will see later, this difference is because, under ARC, the evaluation of the second argument has a side effect that affects the first argument.) So, 1) we figured out that in this case the compiler evaluates the first argument before the second; and 2) since the first-argument-before-the-second case is the one that produces the result you don't understand, your question is really about what is happening in this case.

Update: On second thought, this part might be wrong because assigning it to a variable of block type might cause it to be copied, which is something that does not happen if it is directly passed as argument.

---

So let's get started. `__block` variables are somewhat weird. Similar to blocks, `__block` variables can also start out on the stack, and then are moved to the heap when necessary. (This is documented [here](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/BlockLanguageSpec.html#the-block-storage-qualifier) "An implementation may choose an optimization where the storage is initially automatic and only “moved” to allocated (heap) storage upon a `Block_copy` of a referencing Block." and [here](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/BlockLanguageSpec.html#objective-c-extensions) "The initial Apple implementation does in fact start `__block` variables on the stack and migrate them to the heap only as a result of a `Block_copy()` operation.")

That means the address of a `__block` variable can change over its scope (which is very unusual for a variable in C). When you take the address of a `__block` variable, you take its address at the location that that variable is at that time. That means if you take its address when it's still on the stack, and then later it's moved to the heap, your pointer will not point to the then-location of the variable that everybody else is using at that point. You must be very careful in taking the address of `__block` variables.

What causes a `__block` variable to be moved from the stack to the heap? It's caused the first time when any block that uses it is moved from the stack to the heap (i.e. the first time that block is copied). (This makes sense, if you think about it, because a `__block` variable can only be used outside its scope if some block that uses it exists outside its scope.) In the case of `i`, it starts out on the stack, and is moved to the heap when either of the blocks that capture it is copied for the first time.

When you did `&i` originally, assuming that evaluating a block literal does not cause it to be copied, nothing could have caused `i` to be moved to the heap. So you are taking the address of `i` when it's on the stack. You pass this address to `testBlock()` as `ptr`. Then something causes the first block is copied, causing `i` to be moved to the heap. Subsequently, the `i = 1;` statement later on in the same function, as well as reads and writes to `i` from either of the blocks, operate on the heap version of `i`, which is not the variable pointed to by `ptr`.

What exactly caused the first block to be copied? The block is passed to `testBlock()`, and in `testBlock()`, you call `dispatch_after()` with a block that captures our block. `dispatch_async()` copies the block given to it, and when a block is copied, it in turn copies any blocks it captures. So the block would be copied (and thus `i` moved to the heap) by the time `testBlock()` returns.

This also explains the addresses that you see -- the `point to address:` points to the original stack version of `i` (this is the address you got from `&i` and passed to `testBlock()`). The others, `real address`, `block address`, and `final address`, refer to the heap version of `i`, because they were from running `&i` after `i` had been moved to the heap by the first block copy.

P.S. If you followed the discussion above, you will notice that you are also doing something really bad in your code. Remember that when you passed `&i` to `testBlock()`, you passed a pointer to `i` on the stack. Then `testBlock()` uses this pointer (`ptr`) in an asynchronous operation, where it writes to the location it points to. By the time that the asynchronous operation executes, the original function has exited. (Because the main queue is a serial queue, the next operation cannot possibly start until the previous one is finished.) Therefore, you are dereferencing a pointer to a stack variable from a function call that has already returned. This is very bad *undefined behavior*. You are lucky that it didn't crash or cause bad things to happen.

Comment: Wow :-( And I thought Apple had removed (now that ARC handles the copying) all the weirdness resulting from them surfacing the stack/heap optimisation in the first place.